# Unable to setup an debezium-embedded engine for SqlServer Connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Trying to setup a debezium-embedded engine for SqlServer Connector by using below Configuration

```
config = Configuration.create()
 .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector")
 .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
 .with("offset.storage.file.filename", "/path/to/storage/offset.dat")
 .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000")
 .with("name", "localSqlServerconnector")
 .with("database.hostname", "localhost")
 .with("database.port", "1433")
 .with("database.user", "sa")
 .with("database.password", "pwd@123")
 .with("database.server.id", "12345")
 .with("database.server.name", "localSqlServer")
 .with("database.history", "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
 .with("database.history.file.filename", "/path/to/storage/dbhistory.dat")
 .with("database.history.kafka.topic", "localMysqlServer.dbo")
 .with("database.dbname", "sampledb")
 .with("table.whitelist", "dbo.student")
 .build();

engine = EmbeddedEngine.create().using(config).notifying(this::handleEvent).build();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(engine);
```

below are the dependencies used to establish debezium-embedded engine setup for SqlServer Connector.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
  <artifactId>debezium-embedded</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
  <artifactId>debezium-connector-sqlserver</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the error occuring when i'm trying to start debezium-embedded engine

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.debezium.relational.HistorizedRelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:379) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:682) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:89) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:739) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:934) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:879) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorTask.getAllConfigurationFields(SqlServerConnectorTask.java:220) ~[debezium-connector-sqlserver-0.9.0.Final.jar:0.9.0.Final]
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:36) ~[debezium-core-0.8.3.Final.jar:0.8.3.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:677) ~[debezium-embedded-0.8.3.Final.jar:0.8.3.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813) [na:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.relational.HistorizedRelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:591) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:934) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:879) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Please let me know incase have missed anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to avoid inter APIs comflicts keep t version from same group id same.
You missed `debezium-core` dependecy

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.debezium/debezium-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
    <artifactId>debezium-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
  <artifactId>debezium-embedded</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
  <artifactId>debezium-connector-sqlserver</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Also change the version of all the artifacts with same group id to `1.1.2.Final`
Also add the same jar to your runtime environment's classpath

Comment: Thanks @QuickSilver.
getting the same issue even after adding the ```debezium-core``` dependecy.

Comment: This is more of run time error so also add the jar to your `debezium-embedded engine`'s class path @KolaGangadhar

Comment: but with the similar ```io.debezium.config.Configuration```, it worked for MySQL Connector.

Comment: is everything proper from the configuration attached in the question ?
as I can see the below error in the console.

ERROR 365784 --- [pool-1-thread-1] io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine      : Unable to initialize and start connector's task class 'io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorTask' with config: {name=localSqlServerconnector,......}

Comment: still the same issue after adding ```debezium-embedded engine```  to the classpath.

Comment: looks like you are using older version of jars try using some latest versions

Comment: Thanks @QuickSilver ,It worked for me when i tried with ```1.1.2.Final version``` of ```debezium-core```

Comment: Hi @KolaGangadhar, can you please share the configuration details. It is not working for me. I am getting the following error.

tried to access protected method 'int io.debezium.config.CommonConnectorConfig.validateServerNameIsDifferentFromHistoryTopicName(io.debezium.config.Configuration, io.debezium.config.Field, io.debezium.config.Field$ValidationOutput)' (io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorConfig$$Lambda$592/0x0000000800f53400 and io.debezium.config.CommonConnectorConfig are in unnamed module of loader 'app')